# How can I draw this movement diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Can someone please tell me how to do the diagram below?

[image]

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to do it... I did search online and found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331833/how-to-draw-a-movement-diagram-in-latex
but it isn't quite what I would like...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with a `matrix`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line/.style={-Stealth, shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt}]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, nodes={minimum size=8mm, anchor=center}, nodes in empty cells](A){
& A & B & C & D \\
A & & & & \\
B & & & & \\
C & & & & \\
D & & & & \\};
\foreach \i/\j in {2-2/2-4, 2-5/2-4, 3-2/3-3, 3-5/3-3, 4-2/4-3, 4-5/4-3, 5-2/5-5} 
\draw[line] (A-\i.center)--(A-\j.center);
\foreach \i/\j in {5-2/2-2, 2-3/4-3, 5-3/4-3, 2-4/3-4, 5-4/3-4, 2-5/4-5, 5-5/4-5} 
\draw[line] (A-\i.center)--(A-\j.center);
\draw (A-1-1.north east)--(A-5-1.south east) (A-1-1.south west)--(A-1-5.south east);
\path (A-1-3)--(A-1-4) node[midway, above=3mm]{Colin};
\path (A-3-1)--(A-4-1) node[midway, rotate=90, left=3mm, anchor=south]{Rose};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this solution is very elegant! I never understood why one should use tikz-matrizes, now I do! :)

Answer (score 4):

For one example it is probably easier to hard code everything but since every up arrow meets a corresponding down arrow, and every left arrow meets a right arrow, it seems natural to loop over the heights and lengths of the vertical and horizontal arrows. The main advantage of doing it this way is that this makes it possible to create a macro for drawing these diagrams. Once this is done you can produce the diagrams

[image]

using the lines:

```
    \MovementDiagram{3,1,2,1}{3,1,1,2}
    \MovementDiagram{2,1,3,2}{1,2,3,2}
```

You could make the names `Colin` and `Rose` be parameters to the `\MovementDiagram` macro too. Another possibility, which requires a fraction more work, would be to allow the grid size to be set automatically from the lengths of the vertical and horizontal lists. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\newcommand\MovementDiagram[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, move/.style={arrows={-Latex[width=4pt,length=8pt]}}]
    % loop over the vertical arrows using their heights
    \foreach  \y [count=\x] in {#1} {
       \draw[move] (\x,1.05)--+(0,\y-0.1);
       \ifnum \y<3
         \draw[move] (\x,3.95)-- +(0,\y-2.9);
       \fi
       \node at (\x,4.6) {\AlphAlph\x};
    }
    % now the horizontal arrows using their lengths
    \foreach  \x [count=\y, evaluate=\y as \Y using {int(5-\y)}] in {#2} {
       \draw[move] (1.05,\y)--+(\x-0.1,0);
       \ifnum \x<3
         \draw[move] (3.95,\y)-- +(\x-2.9,0);
       \fi
       \node at (0.2,\y) {\AlphAlph\Y};
    }
    % finally draw the "axes" and Rose and Colin
    \draw(0.5,0.8)--+(0,4.2);
    \draw(-0.2,4.4)--+(4.5,0);
    \node at (-0.6,2.5){Rose};
    \node at (2.5,5.2){Colin};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

    \MovementDiagram{3,1,2,1}{3,1,1,2}
    \MovementDiagram{2,1,3,2}{1,2,3,2}

\end{document}
```